# I keep getting the error "expected ';' at end of declaration"

Tags: objective-c

```
@implementation Fruit{
-(void) setWeight: (int)a{
    weight=a;
}
-(void) setType:t{
    Type=t;
}
-(void) setName:n{
    name=n;
}
```

the error is in the 2nd line shown. i tried the show invisible spaces trick and it didnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need brackets around your @implementation. Instead, you just need to put a @end after it

```
@implementation Fruit
...
@end
```

Answer (score 6):

You've got an open bracket `{` next to your implementation, delete that and make sure your file ends in `@end`

Edit: The other problems are

1. You're writing your setters incorrectly. You need to provide a type like you did for setWeight `int`, for the type and name.
2. If you're going to make your own setters it needs to be _type = t, and _name = n

I just wrote this code and it builds without issue:

```
@interface Fruit : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) int weight;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *type;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@end


#import "Fruit.h"

@implementation Fruit
-(void) setWeight: (int)a{
    _weight=a;
}
-(void) setType:(NSString *)t{
    _type=t;
}
-(void) setName:(NSString *)n{
    _name=n;
}

@end
```

Comment: i already noticed that and took care of it and im still getting the error,

Comment: Never mind, i misread this, after reading it a second time i was able to fix it.

Comment: Be sure to accept it once you're happy with the final answer. Glad it worked.